# How to allow my users to use either mobilen-number or email address to reset their password on Cognito User Pools?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have implemented the code that allows users to reset their passwords via verified email-address using cognitoUser.forgotPassword(). As per the configuration of the Cognito pool, I can either set the email-address or phone to receive the OTP.

But I want to allow users to choose whether they want to receive OTP on phone or email-address to reset the password considering both of them are verified.

[image: Screenshot of Cognito recovery setting]

Is it possible via Cognito service, or do I need to implement a custom solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

The Cognito service will automatically choose how to send the password reset based on your configuration above. Unfortunately this isn't something you can control using the provided SDKs. A custom solution would be your best bet.

See the [AWS Cognito SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#forgotPassword-property) for more information about the underlying calls. This only accepts a username, and in the callback it will tell you more information about what delivery method the service chose.